# entity framework 3-tier architecture to mvc5

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

We have an aspx project developed in entity framework 3-tier architecture. This is an ERP and we already developed 3 to 4 modules of it.

Now we have changed our mind and want to develop the remaining modules in MVC 5. What is the best way to convert the existing project to mvc5, so that we can continue the remaining modules with mvc.
Also is it possible to run entity framework 3-tier inside mvc5, it will be like 3 to 4 modules of the same application will be entity and remaining will be mvc5.